# Get data from MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, json, mongodb, express

I'm trying to load data from MongoDB to my express to eventually show in my html with use of angular. Now I've got it working to get the data, but this only works with one record in the database. If i create multiple records, it gives the following error in the console:

"can't send headers after they are sent"

This is my "get" request in express:

```
router.get('/getdata', function(req, res, next){
var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
var cursor = db.collection('userdata').find({});
cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
  assert.equal(err, null);
  if (doc != null) {
     res.status(200).json(doc);
  } else {
     callback();
  }
});
};
  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
  findDocuments(db, function() {
    db.close();
  });
});
  console.log('Items have been returned');
});
```

Comment: First of all, I would suggest using Mongoose which provides very nice extras to work with MondoDB. After you create your schema you can fetch all the existing objects by simply one mongoose method mySchema.find(err, response). And with mongoose you will not need to open and close connection "manually"

Comment: don't use loop to check null doc , put condition in find like find({{key : {$exists : true}})

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/getdata', function(req, res, next){

  var findDocuments = function(db, callback) {

    //use such codtion that filter null/empty doc
    //replace key with field of your doc
    var cursor = db.collection('userdata').find({'key' : {$exists : true}});

    //return all docs
     if(cursor){
    return callback(cursor);
    }else{
    return callback([]);
       }

  };

  mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   assert.equal(null, err);
   findDocuments(db, function(docs) {
    db.close();

    //send finaly doc here 
    console.log(docs);
    res.status(200).send(docs);

  });
 });

  console.log('Items have been returned');
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. It returns an error in the console: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: check docs using console.log before send or change find condition according to your document schema or mongo driver